# C: POSIX named semaphores fail to be share accross processes

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm having an issue creating named semaphores inside two processes. This is the relevant content for the header file that is being called inside both programs `(semctrl.h)`:

```
int init_sems()
{
  char names[8][5] = {"sem1", "sem2", "sem3", "sem4", "sem5", "sem6", "sem7", "sem8"};
  int failed = 1;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      sem[i] = sem_open(names[i], O_CREAT,00777, i>3);
      failed = failed || (sem[i] == SEM_FAILED);
    }

    return failed;
}
```

`sem` is a global array of semaphores but I doubt this is relevant.

Both programs call this function successfully but when I print the addresses for the semaphores, I get different values for each program. This means they both create a set of 8 different semaphores, therefore, they can't sync properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: _"when I print the addresses"_ - why would you care about that? Can the programs use the semaphores to synchronize information?

Comment: @TedLyngmo If the semaphores are not in the same address space, it means they are not being shared between processes. This is a refactoring, and it used to work, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: An address as seen in one process can very well be the same physical address even if seen as a different address in another process. [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Comment: @TedLyngmo They did have the same address before refactoring.

Comment: Perhaps the OS was upgraded too? Can you post two complete [mre]s of programs that should be able to communicate (but isn't)  and it'll be easier to see if there's a flaw in that.

Comment: The POSIX specification for [`sem_open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html) says: _The `name` argument conforms to the construction rules for a pathname, except that the interpretation of `<slash>` characters other than the leading `<slash>` character in `name` is implementation-defined, …. If `name` begins with the `<slash>` character, then processes calling `sem_open()` with the same value of `name` shall refer to the same semaphore object, …. If `name` does not begin with the `<slash>` character, the effect is implementation-defined._ _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Your semaphore names don't start with a slash — the behaviour is implementation-defined, therefore.  You've not specified which implementation you're using.  Maybe converting the names to `/sem1` etc will resolve the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, this is probably the reason. I will definitely try this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried but it didn't work. I'm on a Linux machine, x86_64 arch using GCC.

Comment: Even without ASLR, why would you expect the semaphore objects to have the same addresses in different processes? The addresses don't matter.

Comment: Silly question time — when you added the leading slash, did you remember to increase the second dimension of the array from 5 to 6?  The compiler might not warn you about the problem.  GCC 11.2.0 with `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3` did not give any warning about: `char names[][5] = { "/sem1", "/sem2", "/sem3" };`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, I did.

Comment: OK  — good.  Sorry that didn't help.  Have you taken a good look at the manual page for `sem_open()` on your machine?  POSIX leaves things implementation-defined.  That means the implementation is supposed to tell you what happens.  It's different from undefined or unspecified — then the implementation is not under any obligation to tell you what happens.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux:

- A named semaphore is a file name in the virtual directory:  /dev/shm
- The individual named semaphores have the format: sem.name where name is from the sem_open() function
- To use the semaphore functions must include the `pthread` parameter when linking
- Always check the returned value from the semaphore functions.  A returned value of 0 indicates success. If a -1 is returned, then check errno for the cause of the failure.
- Note that named semaphore files do not 'go away' when the application exits, but rather a call to `sem_unlink()` is needed.
- Note that if the named semaphore file is not unlinked via sem_unlink(), then it will still be active when that program is again run and the value left in the semaphore from the prior run will still be there.
- The 'access bits' must be set so all the programs that want to access the semaphore can do so.